# Uploading CSV Files with spaces between words and numbers and decimals to Database

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-web-services, csv, aws-lambda

I am trying to load data (CSV Files) from S3 to MySQL RDS through Lambda. So that i have written code in Lambda so whenever csv file is upload in S3 bucket then the data will import to Database.

But if CSV files are having spaces then the data is not importing exactly in database. See below images

CODE:

```
import json
import boto3
import csv
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error
from mysql.connector import errorcode
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

# Read CSV file content from S3 bucket
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    # print(event)
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    csv_file = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    csv_file_obj = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=csv_file)
    lines = csv_file_obj['Body'].read().decode('utf-8').split()
    
    results = []
    for row in csv.DictReader(lines, skipinitialspace=True, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', doublequote = True):
        results.append(row.values())
    print(results)
    
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.ap-south-1.rds.amazonaws.com',database='xxxxxxxdb',user='xxxxxx',password='xxxxxx')
    
    tables_dict = {
        'sketching': 'INSERT INTO table1 (empid, empname, empaddress) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)'
    }
    if csv_file in tables_dict:
        mysql_empsql_insert_query = tables_dict[csv_file]
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.executemany(mysql_empsql_insert_query,results)
        connection.commit()
        print(cursor.rowcount, f"Record inserted successfully from {csv_file} file")
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

CSV FILE
[image]

The Result in DataBase
[image]

So if there is a space in between name or any word, number the data is not uploading correctly and also if there is decimals like (9.2, 8.7) then also it is not uploading exactly.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Simply provide your CSV file to MySQL (make it accessable by MySQL) then import the data using single `LOAD DATA` SQL statement. MySQL can import/parse such file by itself.

Comment: Thank You for your response , will try that

Comment: "not uploading correctly" -- missing?  keep one word, lose the rest?  move rest to next column?  something else?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with this line:

```py
    lines = csv_file_obj['Body'].read().decode('utf-8').split()
```

When no parameters are specified, `split()` will break strings at **whitespaces**.

You should probably use: `split('\n')`

Alternatively:

- Download the file to disk (instead of using `read()`)
- Use the default behaviour of the CSV Reader (which knows how to break on lines)